# problem using nmap with proxychains

Tags: kali-linux, proxy, nmap, proxychains

I'm using nmap with proxychains on my kali

When I write `proxychains nmap -A [Destination]`

I get the following error

```
ProxyChains-3.1 (http://proxychains.sf.net)
Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2016-09-08 20:02 UTC
|S-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|S-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
*** Error in `nmap': free(): invalid pointer: 0x0117ef28 ***
Aborted
```

Any other options like -sT -sF -sX worked fine but just -A options makes that error

Comment: I don't see a question here.

Comment: @Wildcard question is how can i fix that error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't use Proxychains 3.1. It's old and unmaintained. Proxychains-ng works better.

Second, the statement that "-sF -sX worked fine" is incorrect. That is to say, they probably worked, but they did not use your proxy chains. Programs like proxychains, torify, and others only intercept standard socket calls; Nmap uses raw sockets to do most port scanning and all OS detection. If you want to continue using Nmap with proxychains, you should use the `--unprivileged` option, which will turn off features that use socket operations that cannot be hooked. Do note, however, that UDP communication cannot be proxied over many proxy types (SOCKS4, HTTP, etc.) so Nmap's reverse-DNS name lookups will not be proxied either.

Comment: so even if I installed proxychains-ng some operations will not be proxied?

Comment: @AmmarAtef Yes. Only very plain TCP connections will be proxied: UDP and raw sockets will not. I do not know about SCTP but I suspect it would not be proxied either.